# Question about date manipulation python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I basically am very new to Python pandas, so would be great to get the groups help on this one.

Let's say i have two date fields from different sources for every customer ID like below:

```
id  date_source1 date_source2
1    1/11/2017    15/11/2017
2    3/3/2018
3                  4/4/2018
4    1/10/2017     1/9/2017
```

It can happen that a given customer can have both fields populated or only 1 of them populated.

If both are populated, i want to only create a new field date_final as:

1. `date_source2` if its before `date_source1`
2. `date_source2` if it's after `date_source1` but in same month and year as `date_source1`
3. Else, take `date_source1`

In above example, `date_final` would be:

```
15/11/2017 for ID 1,
3/3/2018 for ID 2,
4/4/2018 for ID 3,
1/9/2017 for ID 4
```

Please let me know if this helps.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using pandas `df.apply` to compute a new column based on other column values.  Then you can define a function that takes the row as input and computes what you need.  You can either refer to row elements by name or positionally as shown below.

```
In [44]: import pandas as pd 
    ...:                                                                                 

In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,10,None]})                                


In [46]: df                                                                              
Out[46]: 
   a     b
0  1   0.0
1  2  10.0
2  3   NaN

In [50]: def comp(row): 
    ...:     if pd.isna(row[1]):  
    ...:         return 'invalid' 
    ...:     if row[0] > row[1]: 
    ...:         return 'col_a' 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         return 'col_b' 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                 

In [51]: df['compared'] = df.apply(comp, axis=1)                                         

In [52]: df                                                                              
Out[52]: 
   a     b compared
0  1   0.0    col_a
1  2  10.0    col_b
2  3   NaN  invalid
```

If you go this route, your comparison can be arbitrarily complicated.  You should also handle the NaNs in your data frame.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, how do i deal with the condition of checking if it's same month and year (my condition #2)?

Answer (score 0):

Do just as you described the algorithm in words.
Define a comparison function:

```
def cmpDates(row):
    d1 = row.date_source1
    d2 = row.date_source2
    if pd.isna(d1):
        return d2    # No d1
    elif pd.isna(d2):
        return d1    # No d2
    elif d2 < d1:
        return d2    # d2 earlier
    elif d1.year == d2.year and d1.month == d2.month:
        return d2    # Same month
    else:
        return d1    # d1 earlier
```

and apply it:

```
df['dat'] = df.apply(cmpDates, axis=1)
```

Maybe the detail you didn't know was how to deal with "same month" case.
Now you know.

Another solution: Define the comparison function as:

```
def cmpDates(row):
    d1 = row.date_source1
    d2 = row.date_source2
    if pd.isna(d1):
        return d2
    elif pd.isna(d2):
        return d1
    return d2 if d1 > d2 or d1 + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0) ==\
        d1 + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0) else d1
```

A little shorter script, but the issue of its readability
is open to discussion.

Answer (score 0):

### Use np.where()

```
df['date_source1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_source1'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['date_source2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_source2'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# date_source1 is not populated
c1 = df.date_source1.isna()

# date_source2 is populated
c2 = ~df.date_source2.isna()

# date_source2 is earlier than date_source1, or they have the same Year/Month
c3 = df.date_source2.lt(df.date_source1) | df.date_source2.dt.strftime('%Y-%m').eq(df.date_source1.dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))

# combo condition by the above three
cond = c2 & (c1 | c3)

df['date_final'] = np.where(cond, df.date_source2, df.date_source1)

>>> df
   id date_source1 date_source2 date_final
0   1   2017-11-01   2017-11-15 2017-11-15
1   2   2018-03-03          NaT 2018-03-03
2   3          NaT   2018-04-04 2018-04-04
3   4   2017-10-01   2017-09-01 2017-09-01
```